# MSVCR90.dll error in .exe file on Windows 8 - application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, dll, windows-8

I have built my program with Visual Studio 2010 (os: Windows 8) and produced successfully an .exe file (x64 bit release). Although when I try to run my project I get the error below:

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b).

I downloaded the dependency walker in order to find out more about the cause of the problem. The error I get is a missing file "MSVCR90.dll".

> Loaded "MSVCR90.DLL" at address 0x0000000070300000.  Successfully
> hooked module.
>
> Unloaded "MSVCR90.DLL" at address 0x0000000070300000.
>
> Second chance exception 0xC000007B (Unknown) occurred in "NTDLL.DLL"
> at address 0x00007FF83126CDD0.
>
> Exited "CHEROB.EXE" (process 0x9B8) with code -1073741701 (0xC000007B).

I downloaded the msvcr90.dll from a download page (64-bit), pasted it in the "C:\Windows\SysWOW64" file, but the problem still exists.

Any solutions please?

Comment: install https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=14632

Comment: You are linking against an incompatible version of the CRT. MSVCR90.DLL is the CRT of Visual Studio 2008. You need to link against MSVCR100.DLL (the one that's compatible with Visual Studio 2010). Randomly copying files to **system** folders is not ever a solution. Pasting a 64-bit binary into the 32-bit emulation layer directories is just one of the problems you can cause.

Comment: @IInspectable Should I link the .dll in project properties->Configuration properties -> C\C++->General -> Additional Include Directories?

Comment: I would investigate why the Visual Studio 2008 runtime is a dependency. It is not generally safe to have more than 1 CRT unless the CRTs are isolated.

Comment: Instructions on how to select the correct CRT can be found in the MSDN ([/MD, /MT, /LD (Use Run-Time Library)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3(v=vs.100).aspx)). If that doesn't remove the dependency on the wrong CRT binary, you'll need to check the other modules to find the one, that's causing the dependency on MSVCR90.DLL.

Comment: Btw, `0xC000007B` translates to `STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT`. It's the error code you receive, when loading a 32-bit binary into a 64-bit process or vice versa, for example.

Comment: @IInspectable Is there a way to check which module uses the dependency on MSVCR90.dll?

Comment: Open a developer command prompt, navigate to your application directory, and execute the following command line: `FOR %f IN (*.exe *.dll) DO @(ECHO %f && DUMPBIN /IMPORTS %f | FINDSTR /i "MSVCR90.DLL")`. That'll list all binary modules, alongside the DLL name, if it has a dependency.

Comment: How could I skip the dependency and build the project properly? Should I compile the libraries from scratch?

Comment: While it is *in general* not safe, to have multiple CRT's in a single process, it is not strictly a bug. (The startup failure is probably the result of your copying a 64-bit binary into a 32-bit search path.) A dependency on the VS2008 CRT in your application compiled with VS 2010 can be made to work, but you have to know, which module pulls in this dependency, and whether it can safely coexist with modules linked against a different CRT. If you don't have this information, you need to re-compile the module with the VS2008 CRT dependency or download a pre-built binary compatible with VS2010.

Comment: See [Potential Errors Passing CRT Objects Across DLL Boundaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235460.aspx), if you want to understand, why mixing different CRT's can be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should install the C++ redistributables, have a look here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29
This should fix your problem, don't copy manually the dll.

Comment: I have downloaded this .exe in the past and the message I get now when I execute it is   "A newer version of Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable has been detected on the machine.

A newer version of Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable has been detected on the machine."